# modifiy values of multiple keys at once in python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Is it possible to change the values of multiple keys at once without the loop?

```py
d = {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0}
for k in [1,2]:
    d[k] += 1
```

Comment: can you add an example how you want to update?

Comment: Also please define what "without the loop" mean. Without loop in python? without loop in underlying implementation? Would `d[1]+=1;d[2]+=2` be the answer?

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is *replace* values, then you can use `dict.update`:

```
d = {1:0, 2:0, 3:0}
d.update({1:1, 2:1})
# {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 0}
```

but as far as I know, there's no way to make a *custom* change without using a loop of some sort. You could use a list comprehension to make a new dict to feed to `.update()`, doing it all in one line:

```
d.update({k: d[k] + 1 for k in [1, 2]})
```

but I don't think there's a general solution for modifying the dict in-place in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to use a dictionary's update method, just include the keys you want to update and the values you want them to have.

```
mydict.update(dict(zip(keys, mytupleValues))))
```